# Too many arguments in for

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

In both `for` statements, I am getting the following error:

```
./count_files.sh: line 21: [: too many arguments
./count_files.sh: line 16: [: too many arguments.
```

Can anyone help me ?

```
#!/bin/bash



files=($(find /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-34/include/ -type f -name '[aeiou][a-z0-9]*.h'))
count=0


headerfiles=($(find /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-34/include/ -type f -name '[_a-zA-Z0-9]*.h' | grep -v "/linux/"))




for file in "${files[@]}" 
do
    if ! [ grep -Fxq "linux/err.h" $file ];
    then 
        localcount=0
        for header in "${headerfiles[@]}" 
        do
            if [ grep -Fxq $header $file ];
            then 
                localcount=$((localcount+1))
                if [ $localcount -eq 3 ];
                then
                    count=$(($count+1))
                    break
                fi
            fi
        done
        localcount=0
    fi
done

echo $count
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the problem lines is:

```
if ! [ grep -Fxq "linux/err.h" $file ];
```

The semicolon at the end is unnecessary unless the `then` is on the same line; it is, however, harmless.

It looks as though you want to execute the `grep` command and check whether it produces any output.  However, you've simply provided the `test` (aka `[`) command with four string arguments (plus the closing `]` for 5 in total), the second of which is not one of the options recognized by `test`.

You might have meant to use this:

```
if ! [ -n "$(grep -Fxq "linux/err.h" "$file")" ]
```

(unless you meant `-z` instead of `-n`; the negations are confusing me).  But if you're interested in whether `grep` found anything, you can simply test the exit status of `grep`:

```
if grep -Fxq "linux/err.h" "$file"
```

Hmmm...the `-q` is 'quiet' mode; so in fact the string test won't work since `grep` produces no output.  You want the direct test of the exit status, possibly preceded by the `!` logical *not* operator.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use square brackets around the `grep`.

In shell scripts square brackets are not used for grouping, `[` is a command in its own right (an alias for `test`), and it is the `[` command that is complaining that you've given it too many arguments.

Just make the call without brackets

```
if ! grep ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `for`s to `while`s with `read`s:

```
...
echo "${files}" | while read file ; do
    ...
    echo "${headerfiles}" | while read header ; do
        ...
    done
    ...
done
...
```